# Signing rpm without passphrase

Tags: linux, rpm, gnupg, gpg-signature, gpg-agent

I am trying to disable having any password when I sign , or at least to send it with the signing command.

```
 gpg --list-keys
 /root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
 ------------------------
 pub   2048R/B40C2563 2017-04-11 [expires: 2022-04-10]
 uid                  XXXXX <office@XXXX>
 sub   2048R/42A9A452 2017-04-11 [expires: 2022-04-10]
```

I have gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.27 and libgcrypt 1.5.4

```
cat  ~/.rpmmacros 
%_signature gpg
%_gpg_path /root/.gnupg
%_gpg_name xxxxxxx
%_gpgbin /usr/bin/gpg2
%_no-protection
```

When I run  ( rpm --addsign xxxxxxxxxx.rpm ) I am having popup for password

I found a solution with keygrip that is not working for me

```
  gpg2 --with-keygrip
  gpg: invalid option "--with-keygrip"
```

These are rpm options:

```
rpm --
 --addsign    --delsign    --eval       --help       --initdb     --query           --rebuilddb  --setugids   --upgrade    --version
```

--checksig   --erase      --freshen    --import     --install    --querytags  --setperms   --showrc     --verify

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by adding  `--passphrase-file /path/to/passphrase-file --pinentry-mode loopback` under `%__gpg_sign_cmd` macro in `.rpmmacros`(or whatever you have) file.

Below is `%__gpg_sign_cmd` macro after modification:

```
%__gpg_sign_cmd %{__gpg} gpg --force-v3-sigs --batch --no-verbose --no-armor --passphrase-file /path/passphrase_file --pinentry-mode loopback --no-secmem-warning -u %{_gpg_name} -sbo %{__signature_filename} --digest-algo sha256 %{__plaintext_filename}'
```

Edit: Adding --passphrase-file /tmp/passfile to the .rpmmacro still requires to input the password manually one time. Subsequent attempts to sign files don't seem to need the password entered manually, but the first one does. Adding '--pinentry-mode loopback' seemed to fix this.

Answer (score -1):

It is no possible. But many people use for unattended signing OBS-signd:
https://github.com/openSUSE/obs-sign
https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Build_Service_Signer